# Java Expression Language : Interpolation?

Tags: java, templates, expression, string-interpolation

Greetings,

In the webapplication I am developing , I want to do something like follows:

I Have a Bean like

```
class Gene{
String geneid;
String sequence;
..
}

// EL expression (sometimes should be simple as "${geneid}" without URL pattern)
String exp="<a> href='http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=${geneid}' />";
String outputString=someframeworkobject.somemethod(exp,aGeneInstance);
```

So the outputString is interpolated like : `http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=gene19191X`

Is there any lightweight EL frameworks that I can use for this?

Comment: To add my own question: Can the JSP EL (which would be a fit here) be called from Java code?

Comment: I came across with Apache Common JEXL and Commons EL.But not sure how I can solve this

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133660/open-source-expression-engines-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe [MVEL](http://mvel.codehaus.org/) would work for you.

With a template like

```
 Hello, @{person.getSex() == 'F' ? 'Ms.' : 'Mr.'} @{person.name}
```

you can do

```
 context.put("person", personBean);
 String output = (String) TemplateRuntime.eval(template, context);
```

Check out [this tutorial](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/java/mvel-templating-introduction.html) (where I read about this, I have no experience with MVEL).

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like all you need is the core Java library class [MessageFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html). It is pretty easy to use and allows you to do replacement of templates in a string.

```
String outputString = MessageFormat.format("<a> href='http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term={0}' />", "gene19191X");
```

You can also create an instance of MessageFormat and reuse that with different values.

Other options you could also try are:

- [Apache Commons EL](http://commons.apache.org/el/) - This is built for expressions in web applications.
- [Groovy GStrings](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString) - I use this sometimes to evaluate a 'script'. This has the advantage of allowing more complex logic.

Comment: MessageFormat does not do expressions, though. I suppose you could combine MessageFormat with an expression language, like JUEL.

Comment: i need more dynamic solution,because above 'Gene' bean is just an example.I use many Bean classes and need something like BeanUtils to process the field values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java's String Templates feature.
It is described in [JEP 430](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430), and it appears in JDK 21 as a preview feature.  Here is an example use:

```java
String outputString = STR."<a href='http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=\{someframeworkobject.geneid}' />";
```